# Format Whole Numbers JavaScript with Commas

Tags: javascript

I want to format a number (225121894) so its formatted as 225,121,894 I pull all the numbers from a JSON and sort and process.
Here is my code

```
function getTestStats(jsonData)
    {
       let totalTest = 0 
       let totalCases = 0
       
       jsonData.map(covid =>
       {
           if(covid.tested !== "NA") totalTest += Number(covid.tested)
       })
       document.getElementById('covidTestStatPG').innerHTML += `${totalTest}`
            
    }
```

Comment: already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*
 CODE FOR NUMBER FORMAT
*/
function numFormat(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

console.log( numFormat(224405) );



/*
  YOUR CODE
*/

var jsonData = [{tested:"225121894"}]; // Dummay JSON Data

function getTestStats(jsonData)
    {
       let totalTest = 0 
       let totalCases = 0
       
       jsonData.map(covid =>
       {
           if(covid.tested !== "NA") totalTest += Number(covid.tested)
       })
       
       
       document.getElementById('covidTestStatPG').innerHTML += `${numFormat(totalTest)}`
            
    }
    
    getTestStats(jsonData)
```

```html
<div id="covidTestStatPG"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't decorate your posts with unnecessary formatting and emoji.

Comment: Thanks, This worked Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [**`Number.toLocaleString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).  Not only does this handle the problem of comma-separation, but it handles any type of locale-standard display settings.  Below, I use `en-US`, but not every country/region formats commas the same, so this allows you to change as needed (i.e., to `en-IN` for Indian-English, etc.) without coding it up yourself everytime...

```js
var number = 123456789;

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat).

I've used it before as follows (this is typescript but you get the idea):

```
const locale = "en-US";
static formatNumber(rawNumber?: number) {
  return rawNumber ? Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(rawNumber) : "-";
}
```